# Function for Google Sheets' Script editor with a button for TODAY(), and NOW() in two different columns of which are the next not blank in the column

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

Currently, I'm looking at some simple documentation for vague ways to make a 'button' (image) over a Google sheet to trigger a function on the script editor. I'm not familiar with this type of Syntax, I typically do AutoHotKey, and a bit of python.

All I want to do is have this button populate 2 columns. The current date in one, and the current time in the other (It doesn't even have to have its year or the seconds tbh). I don't know if it matters of what the pages name is based on how the script works. So the range is ( 'Log'!G4:H ).
Like if I were to make it for AutoHotkey I would put it as :

```
WinGet, winid ,, A ; <-- need to identify window A = active
MsgBox, winid=%winid% 
;do some stuff 
WinActivate ahk_id %winid%
```

So it affects any page it's active on. 
I would like to use the same function on the same columns across different sheets. Ideally, that is. I don't care if I have to clone each a unique function based on the page, but I just can't even grasp this first step, lol.

I'm not too familiar with this new macro. If I use this macro does it only work for my client, because of say like it recording relative aspect ratio movements?
IE if I record a macro on my PC, and play it on my android. Will the change in the platform change its execution?

If anyone can point me in any direction as to any good documentation or resources for the Google Sheet Script Editor or its syntaxes I would really appreciate it.

EDIT: Just to clarify. Im really focused in on it being a function that populates from a click/press(mobile) of an image. I currently use an onEDIT on the sheet, and it wouldnt serve the purposes that I want for this function. Its just a shortcut to quickly input a timestamp, and those fields can still be retouched without it just reapplying a new function for a newer current time/date.

EDIT:EDIT: Ended up with a image button that runs a script that can only input to the current cell.

```
function timeStamp() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
        .getActiveCell()
        .setValue(new Date());
}
```

It only works on the cell targeted. 
I would like to force the input in the next availible cell in the column, and split the date from the time, and put them into cells adjacent from one another.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this will help... if the 1st column is edited it will auto-print date in 2nd column and time in 3rd column on Sheet1:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { 
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if( r.getColumn() == 1 ) { 
  var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
  var newDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 
  "GMT+8", "MM/dd/yyyy");
  nextCell.setValue(newDate);
}
if( r.getColumn() == 1 ) { 
  var nextCell = r.offset(0, 2);
  var newDate1 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 
  "GMT+8", "hh:mm:ss");
  nextCell.setValue(newDate1);
}}}
```

**https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/130253/186471**

Comment: Can you only use a single onEdit function per gsheet?

I use a function already to make a column all caps ( they're License plates)

   function onEdit(e) {
       var sheet, sheetName, colToCapitalize;
       sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
       colToCapitalize = 19;
       sheetName = 'Log';
       if (sheet.getName() !== sheetName || e.range.rowStart < 2 || 
   e.range.columnStart !== colToCapitalize || typeof e.value == 'object') return;
       e.range.setValue(e.value.toUpperCase())
   }

Comment: Im really trying to avoid it being an edit.
I would like to have it be just an optional button that can be pressed to quickly populate a timestamp.

Comment: Just as you can put =TIME(NOW(), NOW()), or =TODAY() in a cell.
I want to have the values from that be there, and not the actual formula, so it doesnt autoupdate when refreshing the sheet or when someone 'edits' the cell at any time

Comment: you can run multiple stuff onedit like: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/131081/186471 or you can just name it as you wish and bind it to the button